# Does WCF require configuration to handle different methods of authentication?

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, .net-3.0

A WCF service has been written and can be hosted in any web site. These web sites could use Windows, Kerberos, or Forms authentication.

Is any particular configuration or development required within the service to handle these different authentication types? Or is authentication independent and the service doesn't need to worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good place to start is [patterns & practices: WCF Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guidelines&ProjectName=wcfsecurity), this has a lot of information in regards to authentication and other security areas of concern.